# Missing iAd's in my apps

Tags: ios, iad

I have released 2 apps to the AppStore. Both of them had iAd implemented and tested before release. Neither of them have showed any ads since their release which is now a full 2 months for the first and 1 month for the last one. I have written to the relevant department several times in both cases. With the first one I got the answer that resubmitting the app might solve the issue and in the latter case I have yet to reveive an actual answer(weeks after writing to them).

So it seems hard to get much info from apple regarding the iAds. I have found older threads in  here saying to generally wait for 3-4 days before iAd can be expected to show. However I haven't found much about iAds never showing, so maybe a discussion here could shed some light on this?

Comment: Did you register for iAds within iTunes Connect? Also, what country are you in?

Comment: As far as I know it isn't necessary any more to actively register for iAd. I will post the documentation for that claim, when I find it again.
I'm in Denmark, where iAd has been accepted for a very long time.

Comment: I just went through the process of adding a new version of an already active app. However I didn't see an option to enable iAds during these steps.

Comment: Do you have any warnings when you compile?  I had some warnings in my app about scroll views content size. When I submitted it that way, no ads. Contacted Apple and they said same, resubmit. I resubmitted, nothing. Then I fixed the warnings, all of them, resubmitted and viola, the ads started showing. Don't know why but that's what happened!

Comment: I have one warning 'format string issue', but really can't see how that would affect iAds. Good for you that you found a way to fix it! Wonder when and if the same will happen for me.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think my warnings would affect it either. But try getting rid of them and resubmit.

Answer (score 1):

In order to activate your iAds you need to agree to the network contract and complete the required tax forms. From [Apple Developer Support](https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/iad-app-network/):

*Integrating iAd in Your Apps:*

*To generate revenue through iAd ads in your app, simply do the following in iTunes Connect:*

- *Agree to the iAd App Network Contract.*
- *Complete the required tax forms and, if you have not already done so, set up your banking information.*
- *Integrate the iAd the iAd Framework in your app and submit it for review.*

Comment: Yes I'm aware of these steps and have completed them. When I said that  I believe you no longer need to 'actively register' I was referring to apple making a change in Itunes - at some point in the spring there was a banner on there saying that the procedure had changed so that iAd would now automatically run when implemented into any app.